# Textarea validation after clicking the radio button

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
$.metadata.setType("attr", "validate");
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form1").validate({
        rules: {
            $("#comment"): {
                required: "#welcome:checked"
            }
        }, debug:true
    });
    $("#welcome").click(function() {
        $("#comment").valid();
    });
});
```

It only works if I put the name of the text area instead of id field (code line 5, `#comment`). How to validate through the id ?

Comment: post your html codes too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By initialising the `validate` plugin with the `rules` object, you *have* to use the `name` attribute of the element as the selector. This is because in the specification, the `name` parameter is the only identifying attribute which must be used. All other are optional.

Instead you need to apply the rules to the elements individually, like this:

```
$('#form1').validate();
$('#comment').rules('add', { 
    required: $('#welcome').is(':checked')
});
$('#welcome').click(function() {
    $("#comment").valid();
});
```

Comment: if `(rory.answer.time.posted > kayen.answer.time.posted) alert('not fair')`

Comment: @kayen if (rory.answer.includesDetailOfWhyOPCantUseIdAndExplainsWorkaround) rep++; ;)

Comment: if(OP.question.subject === 'How to validate through ID') { kayen.answer = true; kayen.rep++; }

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
$("#comment").rules("add", { 
  required: $("#welcome").is(':checked')
});
```

Comment: Can you post some HTML so we can `fiddle` it out a bit?